# Conditional graduated styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, choropleth

I want to make a choropleth map from Census data, where my table structure is similar to the below, but I want to create a graduated style for the population based on a particular Country of birth (e.g. for Greece):

```
Region     Country of Birth         Population
1          Australia                52
1          Iraq                     22
1          Greece                   13
2          Australia                16
2          Iraq                     3
2          Greece                   21
```

I've tried doing this via an expression, however, have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: You should show more of your data structure ... Why do you want to build an expression and not access directly your table field ? Why did u title your post "conditionnal" ? ....

Comment: What is your required classification interval, i.e. quantile, equal, Jenks etc.? Is normalization per area necessary in your outcome? What units the attribute `"Population"` has? Is it mandatory for you deploying expression?

Comment: If you use a rule-based style based on the country of birth, you can create a separate graduates style for each rule with the "Refine selected rules" button.